# Can't get result of desired query in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I need to get data of two or three years like from **'Jan, 2017 to March, 2019**' or so. In my query I've separated properties for Year & Month which are compared with SYear(from Year - 2017), Tyear(to Year - 2019) and SMonth(from Month - 1(Jan)), TMonth(to Month - 3(March)). My query is only working for a similar year search like Jan 2017 to Dec 2017. But don't work for Jan 2017 to March 2019.

*Here's my code:*

```
var Bim = new BillingInfoPerMonthManager().GetAll().Where(x => (Convert.ToInt64(x.Year) >= SYear && Convert.ToInt64(x.Year) <= TYear) && (Convert.ToInt64(x.Month) >= SMonth && Convert.ToInt64(x.Month) <= TMonth)).ToList();
```

I need to search like 'Jan, 2017 to March, 2019' where **SYear = 2017, TYear = 2019, SMonth = 1, TMonth = 3**  and get data according to search.

How can I do this, please help.

Comment: The column you are comparing is a DateTime Column?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no, Year & Month both are string type in Database, i'm converting them to Int64 to compare with input values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that Year = 2017 and Month = 9 while this is in the range you want but month = 9 does not fit in `Convert.ToInt64(x.Month) >= SMonth && Convert.ToInt64(x.Month) <= TMonth`

try something like this:

```
var Bim = new BillingInfoPerMonthManager().GetAll()
 .Where(x => (int.Parse(x.Year) * 12 + int.Parse(x.Month)) >= SYear * 12 + SMonth
  && (int.Parse(x.Year) * 12 + int.Parse(x.Month)) <= TYear * 12 + TMonth).ToList();
```